# Has a new practical reason to learn Latin emerged?

Tags: sentence-translation

How would you render:

> If Trump bombs us into the Middle Ages, we'll all need to know Latin.

I'm posting an answer of my own, in hope of constructive criticism (or confirmation that I hit the Latin groove).

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of comparison, here's a different rendering. Wherever possible I tried to make a different decision from yours.

> *Sī Trumps bombīs nōs ad saecula prīsca premet, omnibus Latine loquī necesse erit.*

Latin conditionals are interesting, because the grammar expresses more information than in English. If the condition will happen in the future, the mood of the verbs indicates how "vivid" the condition is. I used a "future more vivid" (indicative) construction here to show that this concern is pressing and important—hopefully not because it is likely to happen in reality.

Since "Trump" ends in a consonant, and apparently comes from a consonant-stem in German, I treated it like a consonant-stem noun *Trumps, Trumpis*.

There seems to be no attested Latin verb for "to bomb [something] back to [something]", despite rigorous searching. So I used the verb *premō* "to crush, to force down", with the preposition *ad* "to". <s>Given the meaning it would make sense to put *re-* in front of the verb, but **repremō* isn't attested.</s> *See comments.* As the instrument by which we are being forced back, *bombīs* is ablative plural.

This is the most difficult phrase to translate, since there's no Classical equivalent: another option (per Tom Cotton) is *rētrōrsus* "backward" with a form of *agō* "drive"; yet another (per Morgan's lexicon, via brianpck) is to use *pyrobolus* for "bombs" with a form of *dēiciō* "hurl [something] down onto".

In Classical Latin, *prīscus* refers to "the old times", when heroes were real heroes and kings were real kings: the long-ago age during which history and legend are somewhat mixed. For instance, *prīsca Latīnitas* is the Latin spoken before Classical times.

*Saeculum* can mean a century as in 100 years, but can also mean an indefinitely long span of time, or more generally an "age" (golden age, iron age, etc). I'm using it in the plural here, per Joonas Ilmavirta's suggestion, to indicate that we might be sent to anywhere in a long time period rather than to a single specific instant.

Just to have something different, I used an impersonal construction for "need": *necesse erit omnibus* "it will be necessary for everyone..." Since *nōs* appears earlier in the sentence I left off *nobis* here. And rather than "know the Latin tongue", which sounds slightly awkward, I used literally "speak Latin-ly" (*Latine loquī*).

Comment: Since _repremo_ is not found, why not use _retrorsus ago_, 'drive backwards' ?

Comment: The Morgan lexicon allows for *bomba/us* and *pyrobolus*: for the verb, it recommends *pyrobolis concutere/verberare* and *pyrobolos deicere*

Comment: @brianpck Thank you for the Morgan lexicon! I didn't know about that. Is there an easily-searchable form online?

Comment: @TomCotton Good thought, I'll note that.

Comment: @Draconis Not that I'm aware of, actually. I have a local copy saved to my computer that I search with find and replace (or regex for trickier cases)

Comment: Good answer! Two ideas: (1) How about *saecula prisca* in plural to indicate an era rather than a specific time? (2) The prefix weakens the vowel in the stem: *re+premere=reprimere*. This verb is attested.

Comment: *Reprimo* exists, as @JoonasIlmavirta says. But the meaning of *re*- there (as often) seems to be not "back again to where one formerly was" but "in restraint", as in "hold back", so it may not be suitable.

Comment: Fantastic answer! So many rhetorical choices here that never crossed my mind. The use of future indicative vs. present subjunctive is something I'll be on the lookout for as I get more experience reading Latin—yes, a subtle distinction that English lacks. Good point about repeating *nos*. *Omnibus Latine loqui necesse erit* is much more elegant and straightforward than my _noscere._

Comment: @TomCotton I definitely like _retrorsus ago_! As I understand that, it connotes both that we would be driven like animals and that the change is for the worse, regressive, a loss of what we've achieved.

Comment: I also really like _deicio_. It's got the downward suggestion of _de-_, perfect for bombs, and [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=deicio#lexicon) even mention a sense of driving someone out militarily. I'm thinking that I came across this word recently in connection with smashing statues or idols by knocking them down—or am I thinking of a different word?

Comment: The Morgan/Owens lexicon (David Morgan died, alas, in 2009, and the lexicon is today maintained by his former student Patrick Owens) is online in several places, including http://www.josephsusanka.com/adumbratio/ and I believe (my computer is being particularly obstreperous at the moment so I'm having trouble checking) at http://www.wyomingcatholiccollege.com/faculty-pages/patrick-owens/lexicon/adumbratio/index.aspx .

Answer (score 3):

> Si Trumpus nos bombet in Medium Aevum, nobis omni sit opus linguam Latinam noscere.

Commentary:

- I chose **Trumpus** to drag *Trump* into Latin somewhat roughly, to avoid **triumphus**, and hopefully to sound a bit ridiculous. To English ears, it evokes the somewhat undignified word *rumpus.*
- I coined a verb **bombare**, from Italian *bomba* (from Latin **bombus**, a "boom"), although now that I look it up, I see that the Italian verb is **bombardare**.
- I put **bombare** into the present subjunctive, since it describes the protasis of a hypothetical scenario.
- I'm thinking that the object of **bombare** should naturally be the victim, not the bomb. I suppose the victim could be in the dative case, but the accusative seems right because I want to suggest that **nos** are being "pushed" **in Medium Aevum**. I'm imagining that if **bombare** has realy currency, it does *not* normally suggest causing the victim to move from one place to another—and certainly not from one time to another. I'm intending this to be a somewhat jarring or unusual use of the verb (as it is in English).
- **Medium Aevum** since Latin was still in common use then, and to suggest misery, famine, feudalism, loss of civilization, and a loss of knowledge, which I think is amusing since knowing Latin today is pretty esoteric knowledge.
- Dative **nobis** because it's our need; we're the ones with a stake in this **opus**.
- Dative **omni** (should be **omnibus** as TKR commented) to emphasize that it's *all* of us. I'm thinking that **omnino** would be wrong here because it's an adverb.
- Present subjunctive **sit** because I'm thinking that the apodosis of this hypothetical situation should still be subjunctive, and a result should have the same tense as the protasis.
- I chose **opus** over **necesse** on the hypothesis that **opus** more concretely indicates a practical need.
- The two-word phrase **linguam Latinam** only because nearly everything I read shies away from the single-word **Latinum**. I understand **Latinus** to be heard primarily be an adjective.
- **Noscere** for knowing a language, since I understand this verb to suggest close aquaintance, familiarity. I considered **Latine loqui** but for some reason I rejected it. Right now, though, I can't see why.

Comment: I would suggest offering some commentary on your translation choices

Comment: *Omni* should be *omnibus*, to agree with *nobis*.

Comment: @brianpck Will do! I haven't read the other answer yet, so this will reflect my naïve thinking. (I read TKR's comment, but I'll leave my mistake so that others can learn from it.)

Comment: @brianpck Done! Now to read the other answer…

Comment: Now I just added some comments to explain some more of the intended rhetorical effect, now that I've read Draconis's excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, I'll add a version with some other possibilities:

> Trump sī nōs tormentīs rētrōrsum conjiciet in minus ērūdīta sæcula hominum, omnibus sermōnem Latīnum callēre opus fuerit.

**Trump**: I'll just note that my preferred moniker for the gentleman in question is *Cynocephalus*, but in deference to those who might esteem him differently I'll just use his name.

**tormentīs**: I was going to go with *pyrobolīs*, but I see that's already in one of the comments, so I threw this in. (I'm not sure I completely buy *pyrobolus* anyway.) I realize *tormenta* does risk creating the image in the listener's mind of Trump as the ringleader at a circus shooting us out of a cannon, but I figure that the idea is fairly clear.

**in minus ērūdīta sæcula hominum**: This is from Cicero, *Rēs Publica*. My computer's being wonky so I can't find the specific passage.

**sermōnem Latīnum callēre**: My default here would be *Latīne loquī*, but I offer this as another option. I also considered *Latīne sermōcinārī posse*.

**conjiciet/fuerit**: I put the protasis in future most vivid, given that I think the possibility of this happening is quite likely. For the apodosis I thought it might be fun to use the future perfect, except imagining it as a perfect future, so to speak: "it have will be necessary for us." That is, in the past, it was necessary that in the future we learn Latin. Obviously *erit* is what's called for here but, hey, it's 3:30 in the morning.

Comment: [Res publica, 2.18:](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/43/2/10455-10459,10472-10480@1#2) *minus eruditis hominum saeculis fuerunt*